# Return 0 if null in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am currently using Spring Data with mongodb. I am trying to do a count aggregation query as follows. It currently does not return results for those counts which are 0. How should I modify the code to return 0 if there is no count for the distributionOfficer?

```
Aggregation aggTodayCount = newAggregation(
                match(where("userRegistrationDateTimeModified").gte(todayStartDateTime)
                        .andOperator(where("userRegistrationDateTimeModified").lte(todayEndDateTime))),
                group("distributionOfficer").count().as("count"),
                project("count").and("distributionOfficer").previousOperation(),
                sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "distributionOfficer")
        );
```

Comment: `.project("count").and(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("distributionOfficer").then(Collections.emptyList()))).as("distributionOfficer")` try this and let me know

Comment: Where would the value of the `distributionOfficer` field come from if there was no document satisfying the `match`?